# SUM() function differences between SQL Server and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm facing a problem with the `SUM()` function with `MS SQL Server` and `MySQL`.

These are the values in the table:

```
docYear    docMonth cli   des   agent      code     flag     doctype     qty
2017       3        C01      D1    A1      12345    X        OR          3
2017       3        C01      D1    A1      12345    X        FA          3
2017       11       C01      D1    A1      12345    X        OR          3
2017       11       C01      D1    A1      12345    X        FA          3
```

This `SQL` query:

```
SELECT
    docYear
,   docMonth
,   cli
,   agent
,   code
,   flag
,   sum(
        case
            when
                doctype =   'FA'
            then
                qty
            else
                0
        end
    )                                       as  qtySum
from
    tableName
group by
    docYear
,   docMonth
,   cli
,   agent
,   code
,   flag
```

returns:

```
2017 3  C01 D1 A1 12345 X 3
2017 11 C01 D1 A1 12345 X 3
```

The same query, with the same data, in `MySQL` returns:

```
2017 3  C01 D1 A1 12345 X 6
2017 11 C01 D1 A1 12345 X 6
```

As you see, the SUM apparently do the work differently between `SQL` and `MySQL`.

There are differences for the `SUM()` function or aggregation rules between `SQL` and `MySQL`?

SQL version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)
```

MySQL version:

```
5.7.23
```

**Edit:** I can't update the versions. And the only `MS SQL SERVER` fiddle online I founded it's not working...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps there's a difference in `CASE WHEN`...

Comment: I would filter the records in the WHERE clause instead of using a CASE. Could you try that so we can find out weather the problem is in the CASE or in the SUM?

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle to prove that? `sum` always works the same, but the `case` might return different data. Of course this should not happen (if there's a case sensitivity issue MySQL should return 0)

Comment: `Type` is a keyword in MySQL. You need backticks around it : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-T ; without that it seems that MySQL is returning true for your `case ..when` for any condition

Comment: And YEAR and MONTH are ANSI SQL reserved words.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya changed to doctype (it's only for the example)

Comment: @user2342558 can your provide a fiddle. This definitely looks like a mistype somewhere

Comment: You can't probably setup a fiddle with such ancient versions of SQL Server and MySQL :-)

Comment: @dnoeth not sure abt SQL Server, but MySQL version is recent patch in 5.7

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya unfortunatley no, the only sql server fiddle I founded online it's not working... freeze on building schema with no error

Comment: @user2342558 I am more concerned about MySQL, because as per the query, MySQL is giving wrong result. So if your provide create table statements; I can test against MySQL

Comment: @user2342558 I get correct results in MySQL 5.6, 5.7, and MariaDB 10.3. May I suggest you examine your input table in MySQL to make sure it has no duplicated data?  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rnpChANLhbAEBK2725w3zx/0

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=846f21145dd57f6de9088178fa174499 fiddle link

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin the fiddle seem to be wrong. It has errors and does not contain my query and data. Also the version isn't the same

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a "problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

Comment: The mostly reason is that the data is different in the two databases.  That is much, much, much, much more likely than `SUM()` being incorrect in either database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "sum" or "case when" in MSSQL Server and MySQL are same, but GROUP BY in MySQL is different to MSSQL Server.

In standard SQL you should use aggregation functions around all of non-aggregated columns.
but in your issue "doctype" column does not exists in aggregation functions or non-aggregated selected columns.

In fact the MySQL way of using GROUP BY differs from the SQL Server way.

In SQL Server when you remove "doctype in select query in fact you select on a list like this:

```
docYear    docMonth cli   des   agent      code     flag     qty
2017       3        C01      D1    A1      12345    X        3
2017       11       C01      D1    A1      12345    X        3
```

and your result in SQL Server is:

```
2017 3  C01 D1 A1 12345 X 3
2017 11 C01 D1 A1 12345 X 3
```

but MySQL logic in GROUP BY differs from the SQL Server and its difference is in dependency on non-aggregated selected columns
in MySQL when you remove "doctype" from non-aggregated columns in fact you have a table like this:

```
docYear    docMonth cli   des   agent      code     flag     qty
2017       3        C01      D1    A1      12345    X        3
2017       3        C01      D1    A1      12345    X        3
2017       11       C01      D1    A1      12345    X        3
2017       11       C01      D1    A1      12345    X        3
```

In this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) describe "MySQL Handling of GROUP BY"